# IntlDateFormatter::Parse returns Date parsing failed: U_PARSE_ERROR

Tags: php, linux, symfony

I am using symfony2 for my application.  During date type form field validation symfony attempts to parse the string date value being passed in.  For some reason this works locally (running MAMP & php 5.3.6) but fails on our remote fedora server. (php 5.3.8). Here's some detils, i'm including anything that *might* be relavent.

When instantiating a new IntlDateFormatter I'm using

```
locale: en_US_POSIX
date format: 2
time format: -1
timezone: America/Chicago
calendar: 1
pattern: MM-dd-yyyy
```

Parse is called on the IntlDateFormatter using a date like **11/21/2012**

```
$timestamp = $this->getIntlDateFormatter()->parse($value);
```

and here's the getIntlDateFormatter method.

```
protected function getIntlDateFormatter()
{
    $dateFormat = $this->dateFormat;
    $timeFormat = $this->timeFormat;
    $timezone = $this->outputTimezone;
    $calendar = $this->calendar;
    $pattern = $this->pattern;

    return new \IntlDateFormatter(\Locale::getDefault(), $dateFormat, $timeFormat, $timezone, $calendar, $pattern);
}
```

the entire class that handles the transforming of string date values into localized datetime values is [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataTransformer/DateTimeToLocalizedStringTransformer.php)...

This results in the failed parse, the error is accessible using: intl_get_error_message()

Here's some snippets from phpinfo() on the remote machine:

[image: Intl Config]

[image: Date Config]

And if it helps... a screenshot of the entire phpinfo()..... http://f.cl.ly/items/3q2q2C3Z0b0K1a0F0c3F/phpinfo%20.png

Comment: Is it possible to provide the invocation code or snippet?

Comment: Yea sure... i'll update the original post.

Comment: Ok, I added the invocation and full php class symfony uses.

Answer (score 3):

I also face this problem and then I search in depth and found that the date format is wrong.you should pick date like this format `'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd H:m'`

SO this is complete list files add this line into filter field

```
->add('createdAt', 'doctrine_orm_datetime_range', array('field_type' => 'sonata_type_datetime_range'), null, array(
   'widget' => 'single_text',
   'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd H:m',
   'required' => false,
   'attr' =>array('class' => 'datetimepicker'))
  )
```

then enter start date and end date in this format `2014-09-29 4:46`

hope this will solve problem